# Replicate data across loadbalanced apache nodes

Tags: apache-2.2, load-balancing, replication, haproxy

I am using haproxy that is pointing on 5 apache nodes, the problem is that I want to replicate apache data between those nodes.
I have installed DRBD and it worked but on 2 nodes only
The rsync is not a good choice because of it's bad performance.
Is there a way to replicate data between the 5 nodes ?

Comment: What kind of latency are you looking for? I'm currently using glusterfs2 and it works pretty well. When I request a file that is not on that server it usually retrieves and replicates the file in around 10 seconds, which isn't quite fast enough to keep the http request from timing out. Glusterfs2 is really depreciated, and I think glusterfs3 (which I haven't used) is actually a lot faster about grabbing files that aren't available locally.

Answer (score 0):

May be, [lsyncd](https://code.google.com/p/lsyncd/) could be a good option, is fast and easy to configure.